# Asp.net HttpModule in directory level web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net

I created a custom http module and want to add this module to the web config. The web application is a project that contains several "sub applications". A sub application is just a folder, and within that folder it has its own web.config. I'm doing this so each application has its own application related contents, stylesheets, configs etc.

Now I created a custom http module. When adding this to the root web.config, the module is working properly. When adding the http module config to the directory-level web.config (e.g. /Applications/MyApplication/web.config) the module is not initialized anymore. Even though the msdn states that the HttpModules config element is also working at directory level. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To echo [Marvin Smit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378586/asp-net-httpmodule-in-directory-level-web-config#comment3300541_2462947), it seems that configuring `<modules>` under a `<location>` in `web.config` simply **does not work** - any modules specified in this fashion are NOT invoked.

What you *can* do is to specify the module at root level, and have it controlled by an `appSetting`, which can be hierarchically specified and overridden as required:

```
<configuration>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="UseCustomModule" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>


  <location path="MyFolder">
    <appSettings>
      <add key="UseCustomModule" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
      <modules>
        <!-- CANNOT add module at this level, hence the overridden appSetting -->
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="CustomnModule" type="MyApplication.CustomModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Then within the code for `CustomModule`:

```
    private static bool ModuleEnabled()
    {
        bool appSetting;
        if (!bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseCustomModule"], 
                           out appSetting))
            appSetting = false;

        return appSetting;
    }
```

ASP.NET will see to it that the appropriate value of `UseCustomModule` for our current location is the one we read.

Comment: I certainly don't like the fact that this is the answer, but thanks for confirming what I has suspected.

Comment: @AakashM : Some observations 1) The ModuleEnabled() method needs a call somewhere, I tried calling it in Init and return if it evaluates to false, could not get it to work from there 2) When the call to ModuleEnabled is in an event e.g. PreSendRequestHeaders, it works. To summarize, Module gets initialized once and then for each invocation, the flag is checked. pls correct me if you see any discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS under your root application select your folder which has own web.cofig with HttpModules defined, right click and select property, on Directory tab click on Create button.

It will create sub application and now HttpModules should work.

Comment: That is not really a solution tbh. It changes the application's root location. Therefore you need a new bin directory in the sub level and have all previously configured items in the new bin if they are not GAC'd. It effectivly changes your runtime model.

I think it's a problem (bug) of not having a physcial folder structure but having virtual directories pointing to different locations on the harddrive which are not ancestor/descendant related! Seems ASP.net is not/partially reading the web.config if its from a v-dir where the folder is not a descendant of the application website folder.

Comment: Just followed up on the research. Its by design.

Modules & Handlers are configured on application level. (Dox state any level, but this is an ondocumented by by design constraint of the service model)

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be possible to create a custom config section that lists out the directories you want to include or exclude your module behaviour?  Your module could then inspect that to see if it should do it's work based on the request URL.

I know that's not quite what you are asking, but would certainly give you the behaviour you need.

Answer (score 0):

Base HttpModule for this case could be the following:

```
public abstract class PathBasedHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public abstract void Init(HttpApplication context);

    protected EventHandler BuildConditionalEventHandler(Action<object, EventArgs> targetHandler)
    {
        EventHandler action = (sender, args) =>
        {
            var settingsValue = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(ModuleEnabledAppSettings);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settingsValue) && bool.Parse(settingsValue))
            {
                targetHandler(sender, args);
            }
        };
        return action;
    }

    protected abstract string ModuleEnabledAppSettings
    {
        get;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```